# Is it possible to allow users of a Shiny app to select columns from a datatable to create groups?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and I'm running into trouble trying to find a method to group columns. In my app, the user uploads an arbitrary dataframe. Since their dataframe will be experimental data, I want them to be able to select columns and group them. For example, col 1 and 2 might be part of group 1 and col 3 and 4 are part of group 2. The intention would be that these groupings can then be used to create graphs or run calculations based only on these columns of the datatable. However, I haven't been able to find a simple way of doing this. Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: What do you want to do with these 'groups' once the user assigns columns to them? Are the number of groups dynamic or fixed?

Comment: @DanAdams The number of groups isn't fixed. Some of the graphs I want to generate are scatter plot matrices and volcano plots. The volcano plots are essentially just scatter plots, but I'd need to be able to colour by group.

Comment: If you have multiple data series as separate columns, it's often best to first do something like `tidyr::pivot_longer()` so that your data are gathered into 'long' format. Then your `group` is a single variable rather than different columns.

Comment: But you should share an example of the input, desired output and code you've tried so far if you want to get more specific help.

Comment: @DanAdams I found a way to do it with an action button and insertUI. I'm wondering though how to save the output to a list. I've included details and code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to select the columns and form groups. I'm also able to use my groups to make plots, etc. I'll post the code here so that anyone who comes across this page will be able to figure it out:
I created an action button and a textOutput so people can see the groups they're creating:

```
actionButton("cr_exp", "Create new biological group")
                                        verbatimTextOutput("choices")
```

For the server piece, I used observeEvent (based on a solution someone else on StackOverflow shared with me):

```
    observeEvent(input$cr_exp, {
      insertUI(
        selector = "#cr_exp",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = selectizeInput(
          inputId = paste0("grp", input$cr_exp),
          label = "Select samples",
          choices = colnames(exp_dff()),
          options = list(create = TRUE),
          multiple = TRUE
        )
      )
      tags$div(id = paste0("grp", input$cr_exp))
    })

 output$choices <- renderPrint({
      lapply(seq_len(input$cr_exp), 
      function(i) {noquote(input[[paste0("grp", i)]])})
    })
```